# Can't Install RPIO -- "Python.h" and 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' error

Tags: python, software-installation, rpio

I'm having an issue where RPIO will not install.  When running `sudo pip install -U RPIO` it returns the error :

```
source/c_gpio/py_gpio.c:28:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
                ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

To get around this problem, I followed the advice from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586012/include-python-h-compilation-terminated-on-linux-mint#34586046).

Basically, "Python.h" is a part of Python Development tools.  Whoever made RPIO is probably not aware that their code doesn't work on a system which doesn't have `python-dev` installed.

To fix the problem, install python-dev:  `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

RPIO should install fine after this:  `sudo pip install -U RPIO`